# как с клиента принять файл на node js express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

с клиента передается файл excel на сервер node js(express). как на сервере его принять и обработать?

Comment: 1) Как он передается с клиента
2) Ваши попытки покажите

Comment: Приведите пример своего решения, и мы подскажем, в чем ваша ошибка и как ее устранить.
Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) - is a node.js middleware for handling multipart/form-data, which is primarily used for uploading files.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const upload = multer({
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home', { test: 'test' });
});

app.post(
  '/send',
  upload.fields([{name: 'fileEmailTo'}, {name: 'fileMessageTo'}]),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(204).json({});
  }
);

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Server has been started at port 5000...');
});
```