# Нужно сделать сохранение загружаемых изображений в папку во vuejs приложении

Tags: node.js, vue.js, rest, frontend, backend

Здраствуйте. У меня есть фронтэнд приложение на vue. Данные я беру из API на другом сервере и сохраняю туда же. Но сохранить изображение туда нельзя. **Мне нужно сохранить изображения в локольной папке и отправить путь этого изображения на сервер**. Как мне это сделать. Спасибо.

Comment: картинки, сохранённые в вашей локальной папке будут доступны только вам. это то, что нужно вашему "приложению"? если картинки должны быть доступны из интернета другим пользователям/посетителям сайта то сохранять их нужно в каких-то общедоступных местах. например, на сервере на котором хранятся данные или на гуглклауде/амазонклауде/яндексклауде или нужно написать и выложить в сеть своё файловое хранилище

Comment: Я имел в виду не локальный комп. А локалную папку на сервере. Просто у меня сейчас есть фронтэнд приложение на vue. И нужно кнему сделать сохранение изображений в папке проэкта. На nodejs. И я незнаю как.

Comment: как-то так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1215192/2659 или вот так https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_dav_module.html (мой любимый способ)