# Как отправить файл на сервер на ноде и там его сохранить?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

Есть небольшое приложение на реакте и оно отправляет на сервер изображение + всякую дополнительную инфу о нем(имя, дата, описание, хештеги, user-folder) через axios.

Эта дополнительная инфа хранится в состояниях компонента и перед отправкой должна как то склеиваться с изображением и посылаться на сервер(как вариант формдатой...)

Так вот, как все это склеить? я ну воообще никакой нормальной инфы не нашел. FormData? а как тогда отправить доп инфу? Еще как то? Но да в любом случае, КАК потом сохранить этот файл на сервере, с помощью `express-fileupload`? Хоть формдата, хоть json, в итоге что `req.body`, что `req.files` пустые(

И не предлагайте мне multer, я не хочу мучаться и через боль и страдания в midleware передавать и jwt, и request, чтобы понять в какую папку мне там сохранять этот гребаный файл, такой гемор, а не библиотека

Comment: как принять файл на сервере используя multer https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1215192/2659 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1337060/2659

Comment: если не хотите multer тогда используйте https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable или https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy. или читайте спецификацию, как работать с multipart